# Sodium and alcohol reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols

I wonder, what happens when sodium reacts with alcohol? What is the reaction mechanism?

I think that sodium is an electrophile that attacks the nucleophile oxygen atom in the -OH-group of the alcohol. Sodium will take one electron and bond with the oxygen molecule, while the bond between the oxygen and hydrogen will break. Am I correct?

Comment: Forms the sodium alkoxide and hydrogen gas. Its a standard way of making fresh sodium alkoxides with methanol/ethanol/propanols etc

Comment: @Waylander - Have you ever done the reaction? I'm guessing that you'd have to do it under a blanket of nitrogen or CO2 to keep the alcohol from catching fire.

Comment: @Waylander - Thanks, so the reaction mechanism that I guessed is correct?

Comment: @MaxW Many times. Depends on the scale, certainly under N2 for larger scale and with cooling as it is exothermic. Smaller scale in a f/c and just let the hydrogen bubble off.

Comment: @Csharpyikes  It is a moot point whether the nucleophilic alcohol is the attacking species as it is in solution and free to move around v the sodium is on the surface of a solid and immobile.

Comment: This is not an electrophile / nucleophile reaction. That would imply 2 electron processes, but sodium reduction is going to be a 1 electron process.

Answer (score 3):

Sodium will not take one electron, as you propose. No, it is a redox reaction : the sodium atom will donate one electron to the Oxygen atom of the $\ce{ROH}$ alcohol, so as to repel one $\ce{H}$ atom and make an alkoxide ion. At the end, a $\ce{Na^+}$ cation and a $\ce{RO^-}$ alkoxide anion are produced in the solution. Of course the $\ce{H}$ atom will join the next $\ce{H}$ atom to produce $\ce{H2}$ bubbles that gets out of the solution. $$\ce{Na + ROH -> Na^+ + RO^- + \frac{1}{2}H_2}$$ The reaction is not dangerous. It will not catch fire if done in a sufficiently large amount of alcohol. I have done it plenty of times in the lab. No problem ! It is even a good way for getting rid of old residues of partially oxidized pieces of metallic sodium, in case you don't know what to do with them.